# Tamaño ancho google charts

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenas tengo esta funcion de google charts

```
 function drawStuff() {

        var button = document.getElementById('change-chart');
        var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div_1');

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Galaxy','prueba1',{role:'annotation'},'prueba2',{role:'annotation'},'prueba3',{role:'annotation'}],
          ['Enero',23.3,'el',12,'el',1,'el'],
          ['Febrero',4.5,'el',22,'el',2,'el'],
          ['Marzo',14.3,'el',15,'el',21,'el'],
          ['Abril',23.3,'el',12,'el',1,'el'],
          ['Mayo',4.5,'el',22,'el',2,'el'],
          ['Junio',14.3,'el',15,'el',21,'el'],
          ['Julio',23.3,'el',12,'el',1,'el'],
          ['Agosto',4.5,'el',22,'el',2,'el'],
          ['Septiembre',14.3,'el',15,'el',21,'el'],
          ['Octubre',23.3,'el',12,'el',1,'el'],
          ['Noviembre',4.5,'el',22,'el',2,'el'],
          ['Diciembre',14.3,'el',15,'el',21,'el'],

        ]);

        var materialOptions = {
          width: 2500,
          height: 700,
          chart: {
            title: 'ISC Histórico por mes'
          },
          series: {
             // Bind series 0 to an axis named 'distance'.
            1: { axis: 'brightness' } // Bind series 1 to an axis named 'brightness'.
          },
          axes: {
            y: {
              distance: {label: 'parsecs'}, // Left y-axis.
              brightness: {side: 'right', label: 'apparent magnitude'} // Right y-axis.
            }
          }
        };

        var classicOptions = {
          width: 900,
            title: 'ISC Histórico por mes',

          series: {

            1: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
          }

        };

        function drawMaterialChart() {
          var materialChart = new google.charts.Bar(chartDiv);
          materialChart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(materialOptions));
          button.innerText = 'Cambiar a Clasico';
          button.onclick = drawClassicChart;
        }

        function drawClassicChart() {
          var classicChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chartDiv);
          classicChart.draw(data, classicOptions);
          button.innerText = 'Change a Material';
          button.onclick = drawMaterialChart;
        }

        drawClassicChart();
    };
```

en esta parte `width: 2500,height: 700,` se supone que modifico pero no veo los cambios, algo estoy haciendo mal?
mi HTML

```
<div class="flex-grid">
          <div  class="col">
            <div  id="graficas_isc"  class="gr_isc">

              <button id="change-chart">Vista Clasica</button>
              <br><br>
              <div id="chart_div_1"></div>

            </div>
          </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: vi el problema lo resolvi

Comment: Podrías ponerla como respuesta por si puede ayudar a otros.

Answer (score 0):

La función que se encarga de pintar la gráfica en tu caso es drawClassicChart();, si ves dentro de esta, encuentras que la variable de OPCIONES que se usa es classicOptions --> classicChart.draw(data, classicOptions); y estas colocando las propiedades de ancho y alto dentro del OPTIONS materialOptions ... Debes colocar estas propiedades dentro de classicOptions para poder ver los cambios reflejados en tu gráfica. 
:D